# ハンバーガーメニューが常に表示されている

Tags: html, css

HTMLに

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="home.css" >
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <title>Home</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="page-container">
        <nav class="menu">
            <header>
                <h1>WEB SITE</h1>
            </header>
            <input id="nav-input" type="checkbox" class="nav-unshown">
            <label id="nav-open" for="nav-input"><span></span></label>
            <label class="nav-unshown" id="nav-close" for="nav-input"></label>
            <div id="nav-content">
            <ul class="sidebar-ul" id="menu">
                <li>
                    <a class="home" href="home.html">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a class="profile" href="profile.html">Profile</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            </div>
            <ul id="social">
                <li>
                    <a class="contact" href="">
                        <i class="icon_head" aria-hidden="true"></i>Email</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a class="contact" href="">
                        <i class="icon_head" aria-hidden="true"></i>Facebook</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <main>
            <div id="carousel-container">
                <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                    </ol>
                    <div class="carousel-inner">
                        <div class="item active">
                            <img class="img-responsive" src="test1.jpg" alt="Arch">
                            <p>WELCOME</p>
                        </div>

                        <div class="item contain">
                            <img class="img-responsive" src="test2.jpg" alt="Nature">
                            <p>MY SITE</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </main>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

と書いて、CSSに

```
@media all and (max-width: 1500px) {
body,
html {
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%;
}

#page-container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 3fr;
    grid-template-areas: "NAV MAIN";
    height: 100%;
}

nav {
    grid-area: NAV;
    background-color: black;
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-areas: "HEADER" "MENU" "SOCIAL" "COPYRIGHT";
}

.nav-unshown {
  display:none;
}

main {
    grid-area: MAIN;
}

header {
    grid-area: HEADER;
}

header h1 {
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 30px;
}

#menu {
    grid-area: MENU;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    padding-left: 0px;
}

#menu>li {
    margin: 10px 10px;
    padding: 2px 0px;
}

#menu>li:hover>a {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#social {
    grid-area: SOCIAL;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    padding-left: 0px;
}

#social>li {
    margin: 10px 10px;
    padding: 2px 0px;
}

#copy-right {
    grid-area: COPYRIGHT;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
}

#carousel-container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

li {
    list-style: none;
}

li a {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 20px;
}

.icon_head {
    padding-right: 10px;
}

.carousel {
    height: 100%;
}

.carousel-inner {
    height: 100%;
}

.carousel-inner>.item {
    height: 100%;
}

.carousel-inner>.item>img {
    height: 100%;
}

.item {
    position:relative;
}

.item p{
    position: absolute;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 3em;
    top: 20%;
    left: 50%;
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
}

@media all and (min-width: 500px) {

#page-container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 4fr;
    grid-template-areas: "NAV MAIN";
    height: 100%;
}

nav {
    grid-area: NAV;
    background-color: white;
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-areas: "HEADER" "MENU" "SOCIAL" "COPYRIGHT";
}


/*アイコンのスペース*/
#nav-open {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30px;
  height: 22px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

/*ハンバーガーアイコンをCSSだけで表現*/
#nav-open span, #nav-open span:before, #nav-open span:after {
  position: absolute;
  height: 3px;/*線の太さ*/
  width: 25px;/*長さ*/
  border-radius: 3px;
  background: #555;
  display: block;
  content: '';
  cursor: pointer;
}
#nav-open span:before {
  bottom: -8px;
}
#nav-open span:after {
  bottom: -16px;
}

/*閉じる用の薄黒カバー*/
#nav-close {
  display: none;/*はじめは隠しておく*/
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 99;
  top: 0;/*全体に広がるように*/
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: black;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: .3s ease-in-out;
}

/*中身*/
#nav-content {
  overflow: auto;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 9999;/*最前面に*/
  width: 90%;/*右側に隙間を作る（閉じるカバーを表示）*/
  max-width: 330px;/*最大幅（調整してください）*/
  height: 100%;
  background: #fff;/*背景色*/
  transition: .3s ease-in-out;/*滑らかに表示*/
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-105%);
  transform: translateX(-105%);/*左に隠しておく*/
}

/*チェックが入ったらもろもろ表示*/
#nav-input:checked ~ #nav-close {
  display: block;/*カバーを表示*/
  opacity: .5;
}

#nav-input:checked ~ #nav-content {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(0%);
  transform: translateX(0%);/*中身を表示（右へスライド）*/
  box-shadow: 6px 0 25px rgba(0,0,0,.15);
}

}
```

と書きました。このHTMLにアクセスした時、ハンバーガーメニューが常に表示されています。
ハンバーガーメニューは500px以下の時に表示したいのですが。
500px以下の時のHTMLの構成は
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
のようにして、それ以上の時の構成は、
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
のような配置にしたいです。CSSに

```
.nav-unshown {
  display:none;
}
```

のように書けば、ハンバーガーメニューは表示されないと思っていましたが、それは間違いでした。しかし、どのように修正すればいいのでしょうか？どのように書き直せば意図したアウトプットになりますか？
ハンバーガーメニュー作成で参考にしたサイトは、https://saruwakakun.com/html-css/reference/nav-drawer　のサイトです。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

まずメディアクエリの組み立て方が間違っています。
https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries

・max-width
ブラウザ幅が指定した幅よりも小さい時に適用される。
`max-width: 500px`とすると、ブラウザ幅が 500px 以下の時にスタイルが適用される。

・min-width
ブラウザ幅が指定した幅よりも大きい時に適用される。
`min-width: 500px`とすると、ブラウザサイズが501px 以上の時にスタイルが適用される。

```
@media all and (max-width: 1500px) {
  //1500px以下の時適用するスタイルA
}
@media all and (min-width: 500px) {
  //500px以上の時適用するスタイルB
}
```

という記述になっているので
画面サイズが1500~のときはBが適用
画面サイズが500~1500の場合はAとBが適用
画面サイズが～500の場合はAとBが適用

となっています。
500px以上のときはA
500px以下のときはB
という形にしたい場合は

```
@media all and (mix-width: 500px) {
  //500px以上の時適用するスタイルA
}
@media all and (max-width: 500px) {
  //500px以下の時適用するスタイルB
}
```

その上でmenuなどのメディアごとのコンテンツの表示非表示を制御していくと良いと思います。